# Bind textboxes in an editable combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I need to have editable textboxes on a dropdown.

```
 <ComboBox IsEditable="True"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MethodTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding MethodNames}"
                  SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMethod}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        </ComboBox>



<DataTemplate x:Key="MethodTemplate" DataType="{x:Type models:MethodDetail}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--To display selected combo values i.e Method Name-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding MethodName}" ></TextBlock>
                <!--<TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Parameters ,Converter= {StaticResource listToStringConverter}}"/>-->
                <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="Blah"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="Blah"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

To describe the problem, I have methods and parameters for those methods on the dropdown, I need to bind controls (textboxes) for the user to enter parameter values within them. When the combobox is not editable then the textboxes show up, but they are not editable.

Comment: Bind them to What ?
Do you want them to be editable even if the ComboBox isn't ?! 
How would you even open a ComboBox which isn't Enabled ?

Comment: The combobox is editable and when it is you can pass in only 1 display member, what I want to do is, have texboxes in there instead of only one display text.

Comment: bound to what ? 
post your itemssource and explain what you want to bind to. 

put some more effort into your question if you want a serious replay.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that has to be corrected

1.Setting isEditable="True" to a ComboBox does not help in editing the ComboBoxItems.
2. DataTemplate should be defined in the Resources section. Either in  or 
3. you are using Both SelectedValue and SelectedIndex at a time, which is not correct. 
4. DataTemplate does not need a ItemsControl in it. You can manage everything using Grid control also.

If all these are set right, the code runs fine for me. Here's the code:

```
<Window x:Class="minimizeApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MethodTemplate" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--To display selected combo values i.e Method Name-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding TBProperty}" ></TextBlock>
                <!--<TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Parameters ,Converter= {StaticResource listToStringConverter}}"/>-->
                <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="Blah"/>
                        <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="Blah"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ComboBox IsEditable="True"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MethodTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding MethodNames}"
                  SelectedIndex="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        </ComboBox>      
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you bind the DataContext correctly, the code should run just fine. :)